# choose one list. choose the one whose nth element is the smallest. Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, list

I have two lists. I have to choose one. I have to choose the one with the smallest nth element. So I can choose the smallest element easy with min, but how do I back track it to the list itself. Have literally no idea how to solve this presumably easy problem.

a = [2,45,1,56]
b= [0,23,3,87]
Which list has the smallest element at position 2? The answer here is list a.

In case I wasnt clear, the program sould be able to solve this task for any pair of lists.

Comment: You have to give us the example of what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a very simple snippet that does what you want, but you might want to check for the size of the arrays, in case the index is out of range.

```
def choose_smallest(a, b, i):
  if len(a) >= i or len(b) >= i:
    return 0 # do whatever you want here
  if a[i] < b[i]:
    return a
  else:
    return b
```

Also notice that both nth elements in your array can have the exact same value... In this example array `b` will be returned, but you can change that behaviour if needed.

**EDIT**

Added array length check

Answer (score 1):

According to your example, here is a sample code you can try. You can change the code as per your requirement.

```
a = [2,45,1,56] 
b = [0,23,3,87]
n= int(input('Enter element number: ')) # n starts from zero to length of list - 1
if a[n] > b[n]:
    print('List b has smaller nth element')
elif a[n] < b[n]:
    print('List a has smaller nth  element')
else:
    print('Both lists have equal nth element')
```

Comment: yEAH. So simple and why couldnt I figure it out? Im stupid

Comment: @FredSwed It happens early on. You will learn as you code more and more and apply logics properly.